# Request access to API endpoint Instagram (Relationships)

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm developing a social marketing service that is integrated with Instagram. When consumers enjoy our promotion campaigns on the service,
they also can follow Instagram account of Brands via API if they are interested.

So, I want to use API endpoints with POST relationships for that.

I'm trying to fill this form for registration, but I can't register with 'Anyone' option
https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/contact/185819881608116

Please suggest me what to do?

** Who will be able to use our application? ⇒ Consumers

** Which the endpoint for request access? ⇒ Relationships

** How our application use this endpoint? ⇒ Allow consumers can follow Brands's account if they are interested.

Our request can be approved? Please confirm help me!

Thanks !

Comment: did you find your answer? I'm writing an follow and un-follow which you can find who followed you and who is not. i don't know what to do? have you figure it out what to do?

Comment: I think they don't approve this permission.
And we already used an alternative solution.

Comment: What is the alternative solutions that you follows ?